# How do you animate an SVG path using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

is there a way that I can animate the "d" attribute of the following svg path?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<path id="theEl" d="M0 0, L 0 500, L 600 500, L 600 0" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>
```

If I want to change it I know that this would be enough:

```
document.getElementById('theEl').setAttribute( 'd', 'M0 0, L 0 200, L 200 200, L 600 0' );
```

But what if we want this to animate/morph? Say I have a button that on click it toggles between these 2 paths.

I've seen a couple of answers about it and they suggest to create an SVG animation element and then add it to the svg DOM element. But this would mean that every time the button is clicked we would need to append/remove that animation element right? Isn't there a simpler way? Without using any svg libs?
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Just create the SMIL animation statically i.e. as markup as a child of the path and have it run when the button is clicked.

```
<animate begin="click" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the animation elements to the svg directly, no need for scripting.

For a neat example and some further details, see [this blogpost](http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=741) by Tavmjong Bah.